# Is mongodb suitable for a SaaS platform for managing and distributing travel inventory with reservations?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

We are building a saas platform for managing/distributing travel inventory (hotel, rentals, coaches, restaurants, airlines, rail, activities & events) and distributing them through multiple channels.

In this usecase there will be 4 kinds of users (travel agents, suppliers, tour operators and customers) each with access to the system from different web-interfaces tuned to their requirements for managing their inventory and for making reservations.

Having tested a prototype, we discovered that it was difficult to ensure atomicity with multiple users using mongo even if we denormalized the data model. We wanted to know whether anyone has encountered the same challenges and how they solved them, as the startup application will need a blazing fast persistence layer to be cost-effective and handle over 5000 users as of 15th December.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider some changes in you schema to enable a transactional behaviour. (Priority Queues) and using TTL-Collections to get rid of background workers for not completed bookings.

There are some Schema Design Slides out there explaining how to do that in MongoDB. Here is one example: [MongoDB State Machine](http://www.alvinonmongodb.com/2012/07/schema-design-2-workflows-state.html)